# td background-color not change when i hover it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is my code.i'm hover first tr in table previous class background colors will not change in first two td in first tr.but only when i'll hover first tr must change 1st two td background color will change,where i'm missing some code.it's possible only in css

```css
.cls{
background-color:red;
}
[data-class*="weeks"]:hover{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><th>row2</th><th>row3</th><th>row4</th><th>row5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td class="cls">1</td><td class="cls">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why are you using *="weeks" in your selector instead of just ="weeks"?

Comment: add like this [data-class*="weeks"]:hover td{
background-color:blue;
}

Comment: now can you please make my ans correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
like this

```css
.cls{
background-color:red;
}
[data-class*="weeks"]:hover td{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><th>row2</th><th>row3</th><th>row4</th><th>row5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td class="cls">1</td><td class="cls">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've specified background colors for your `<td>` tags in your `.cls` block. When you change the `<tr>`'s background color on hover the `<td>`s don't lose their own styles, and they'll always be sitting "on top" of the `<tr>`'s background, so to speak. To fix this, specifically selectd the `<td>` children of the `<tr>` being hovered over, e.g.:

```css
.cls{
  background-color:red;
}
[data-class*="weeks"]:hover td {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>row1</th><th>row2</th><th>row3</th><th>row4</th><th>row5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td class="cls">1</td><td class="cls">2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-class="weeks">
      <td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the style:

```
.cls {
    background-color:red;
}
[data-class*="weeks"]:hover .cls, [data-class*="weeks"]:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```